# Spring binding map which contains List

Tags: java, spring, binding

I'm trying to bind `Map<String, org.springframework.util.AutoPopulatingList<B>>` with Spring Framework and I am getting Following Exception:

```
ERROR [jsp:165] org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'command.map[key][0]' of bean class
troller.form.CommandForm]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'map[key][0]': returned null
```

Command object is like this:

```
public class Command {
   private Map<String, AutoPopulatingList<B>> map;
   //getters and setters for map
}
```

And B class is like

```
Public class B {
    private String name;
    private String age;
}
```

and JSP code is like this

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${command.map}">
    <c:forEach var="b" items="${entry.value}">
         <form:hidden path="command.map[${entry.key}][${status.index}]" />
         <c:out value="${b.name}" />
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

I think I should also mention that the Map is dynamic so I can't know how many entries there is or which size Map's Lists will be. And problem occurs when I'm adding new entry to map.

I know that this relates to initializing List's in Map but does isn't that why it is recommended to use AutoPopulatingList so there should not be any initialization related problems?

Can this be binded with Spring Framework at all?

Comment: are you sure that you can address the map like this with EL? it seems like you are trying to access a matrix field. I'm just guessing, maybe you need some extra brackets: (command.map[${entry.key}])[${status.index}] ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that map can be used with EL like that. Even generated HTML shows correct input element and if I populate the map from database I can add more B-objects to existing List.
Let's say I have map with content [key1[b1,b2,b3]] and I would like to add to it [key2[b3,b4]] then I get NullValueInNestedPathException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem just by prepopulating the map and arrays inside the map objects.
So to create it, use

```
@ModelAttribute(FORM_PRECRUISE_SHOPPING) 
@Valid 
PrecruisePlannerShoppingForm form
```